# Yeoman changing picture file names, not updating in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, yeoman

I've been building an Angular app with the help of Yeoman and I am finding it to be pretty delightful except for one small thing.

When I build and deploy my project with `grunt serve:dist` all of the images I use are broken.  This is because Yeoman is changing the filenames of every single picture but doesn't bother to update the HTML.  However, it does update the CSS.

For instance, if I have a picture called `default_picture` and I am using it in my HTML like so:

```
<img src="../images/default_picture.jpg" alt="#">
```

When the project gets built, Yeoman changes the file name of the image from `default_picture` to something like `default_picture.cbed2a58.jpg` but the `src` in the `img` tag is never updated, so images no longer have a reference to a valid image in the directory structure.

I've scoured the Yeoman project on Github and I can't seem to find the answer to this.

How do I fix this so I can either update the HTML properly or just stop changing my image file names?

Comment: Are you inserting the images via angularjs by any chance? Have the same issue. The images not loading are being created by an angular module.

Comment: @RGBK, no, I was just inserting them into the HTML.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only solution I was able to come up with to workaround this issue was to comment out this line:

```
// Renames files for browser caching purposes
filerev: {
    dist: {
        src: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            // '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
        ]
    }
}
```

For me this was on line `214` in the `Gruntfile.js`.  There might be a solution to this, but this is a temporary fix.

Comment: This is is the solution that I used in the past. I don't see much of a reason for `filerev` anyway.

Comment: @JaredCubilla I think this is more sanity checking than anything.  If I have a file with the name of, say, `hello.png` and I would like to change the picture in Photoshop or something and save it again as `hello.png` and replace the file, the browser will sometimes cache the previous image and you will still see the old file rather than the new one.  So, I get the reason but it just flat out doesn't work.

Comment: I see your point. In my case, I don't usually worry about caching pictures, unless they're favicons. I get why `filerev` would be useful. I still used the filerev task, but only removed the filerev for my fonts and images.

Answer (score 1):

Usemin is not searching in the subsubfolders, unless you specifically mention it (like I did in the snipplet from the gruntfile.js below (cfr. '<%= yeoman.dist %>/views/{,*/}*.html'):

```
// Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/views/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>','<%= yeoman.dist %>/images']
      }
    }
```